# ssh from another server and do a git pull

Tags: git, ssh

I'm trying to ssh from another server 1 to server 2 and do a git pull from server 1 to server 2.

So on server 1, I run the following command:

```
ssh root@server2 'cd /root/.example; git pull origin master'
```

but that gives me the error

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

It's able to ssh because when I do an ls I see the contents of the /root/.example directory. It's just not able to do a git pull origin master because it uses the wrong key.

What can I do differently?

I'm using Centos 6.

When I do `ssh root@server2 'cd /opt/example; eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"; ssh-add /root/.ssh/gitkey; git pull origin master'`

the git pull command works

Comment: It may be a bit unrelated but I'm just sharing something that may be useful for you : You could use ```ssh://<user>@<host>[:<port>]/path/to/repository``` as a git distant repository. and push to it. For instance : ```git remote add server2 ssh://root@server2/root/.example; git push server2 master```. But this requires to set ```receive.denyCurrentBranch``` to ```ignore```. But this doesn't solve the actual problem.

Comment: What's the URL of the ```origin``` remote from the repository on **server2**?

Answer (score 1):

ssh on server2 is using public key authentication.  You'll need to create a public/private key pair on server1 (if you don't already have one) and then put the public key in server2's authorized_keys file.

A good intro to this:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that your ssh key is not set properly in the Server 2 make sure that it is set it is also possible that your Server1 does not have recognize the ssh key.

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate an SSH key for server-1 and add the public key to your github account.

Following document will point you in right directions:

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/